# Why does object's memory profile need to be known at compile-time for stack placement?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, low-level

It seems to be a well-accepted fact that if you instantiate an object in a language like C++, it is only eligible for stack placement (as opposed to heap allocation) if the size of the object is known at compile time. For example an array of fixed size can go on the stack but the elements of a vector will be placed on the heap since the final size is unknown during compilation.

Why is this the case? Why can't stack space be dynamically allocated during runtime by moving the stack pointer?

EDIT: For clarification, here's an example: in the middle of a function, you compute a non-const integer. If you want to create an array of this size, the allocation must be done on the heap because the size of the array is not known at compile-time. But why can't you just put the array at the top of the stack when it is created?

Comment: It's unsafe to move the stack pointer arbitrarily as it's mainly used as "call stack"

Comment: Just an FYI. The C++ standard does not use stack or heap. It's a term used only when talking about specific implementations. A compiler is free to use non-stack memory for automatic objects. Why they choose to use stack memory for automatic objects is beyond my expertise.

Comment: Call stack is a contiguous memory that grows/shrinks only from one end, so how could you place any non fixed size structure inside it? That doesn't mean that is it theoretically impossible but that for performance reasons you don't want to.

Comment: Are you asking why dynamic objects (such as vector) can't go on the stack, or why an object such as `std::array<float, n>` (whose footprint after allocation won't change) can't?  (the latter can be put on the stack via `alloca` if your compiler supports it)

Comment: In other words: why doesn't C++ accept VLA like C? I think adding that search term makes it easier to find relevant information.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Good call, thanks for the tip!

Comment: its a compiler implementation thing, not a language thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
void extend(std::vector<int>& v, int val) {
    int w = abs(val);
    v.push(w)
}

std::vector<int> v(10);
extend(v, 3);
```

If the content of `v` is on stack, it will not be continuous since there's other stuff between v[9] and the newly pushed v[10]. Worse, if the operation is forced, then v[10] will almost surely overwrite something.

Comment: I think the OP is asking the inverse question. If you define `int array[10];` as a function variable, why can't memory for `array` be allocated from some place other than the stack?

Comment: I agree, the vector would no longer be stored contiguously because v[10] would be placed at the top of the stack, after w. This doesn't seem very problematic to me, ignoring that the vector spec says it will be contiguously stored. But in general, I still don't see why you can't have dynamic allocations on the stack.

Comment: Perhaps the question to ask is:  What benefit would you hope to gain via the imagined functionality?

Comment: @RSahu If then, there's VLA in C99 (but not C++) that some implementations *does* allocate dynamic arrays on the stack, so the answer is YES.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the function `alloca()` for gcc, and the functions `_alloca()` and `_malloca()` for Microsoft compilers.

This looks as follows:

```
void allocatesArray(int i)
{
    char *ray = reinterpret_cast<char*>(alloca(i));
    // 'i' bytes of memory allocated, returns void * 

    ray[0] = 'a';
    // space freed, pointer invalidated
}
```

Mind that it is not considered as a very good practice because of undefined behavior in the case of a stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

What you can't do unless you're at the very top of the stack is resizing, since you can't move the entire stack around. If you have some data structure that may change size in any way, you cannot use it in any function call from your current scope with a non-const context.

If you're just thinking about this as a possible way to optimize things, clang already does so called "heap elision" to do these kinds of optimization when applicable.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but it seems like the "very top of the stack case" is the default case. For example, the control flow is in the middle of a function, it has just computed a variable not known at compile-time, and then it needs to create an array of that size. Why can't it just put this array at the top of the stack, even though it's size was not known at compile time?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be able to? Pretty sure GCC has had an extension for variable sized stack arrays for a while now. Maybe this is something compiler writers should look into for further optimization though.